# Can I make grunt-open kill port 9000 instead of throwing an error?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

It seems to be a common error, when working with Yeoman and running `grunt server`, but if something fails or you do not interrupt it with Ctrl+C it will keep the process on port 9000 open. Then when you try to do another `grunt server` you get an error, and you need to do `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:9000)` or `sh killport 9000` to make the port available again. Can grunt just automatically kill port 9000 before doing the open?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if grunt-open has this feature but you can use [grunt-exec](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-exec). Later add the exec target to the serve target on your Gruntfile.